# The "process" of long-term excessive use of alcohol

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This is the kind of a Winter Holidays related question:
How is the "process" of long-term excessive use of alcohol during the holidays called in the US and GB?

The Multitran dictionary gives me these phrases:

- barrel fever
- skull cramps
- hang-over
- bottleache

But I don't really sure if these words are of a wide use in the US.

P.S. I'd also like to know how is the "recovering" from the "process" mentioned previously called.

Comment: A hangover is what you get the morning after the night before. It should be relatively short-lived! Long-term recovery from long-term use of alcohol might be called ***drying out***.

Comment: I have never heard any of these phrases, apart from "hangover" (UK).

Comment: There is also in the UK the expression, "going on a [**pub crawl**"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pub_crawl) but that's limited to one night of heavy drinking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two terms that come to mind are...

> [***Binge*** [drinking]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binge_drinking)
>    and
>    [***Bender***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bender)

In my experience, *binge* is more likely to be associated with *rapid consumption* of large amounts of alcohol in a relatively *short period* of time, but either can also be used for extended heavy drinking over a week or more (while on holiday, for example).

When the extended drinking spree finally ends, you'll be *on the wagon, drying out, detoxing*, etc.

Comment: Agreed. *Bender* seems longer (like a weekend or longer) and possibly more habitual then *binge*.

Comment: @KitFix: I think so too, but I would just say that Google Books claims almost twice as many instances of [week-long binge](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22week-long+binge%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) as [week-long bender](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22week-long+bender%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Also, *binge* is often associated with *eating*, but *bender* is almost exclusively reserved for excessive alcohol consumption.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  But these are terms which apply to one drinking session (or, in the case of 'binge', eating or drinking). The OP seems to be seeking a name for the repeated heavy-drinking, over the twelve days of Christmas. I can't think of anything.

Comment: @WS2: I don't really see that. The links in my first comment are to a couple of thousand written instances of *week-long binge/bender*, and here are a couple of [twelve-day binges](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22twelve-day+binge%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for good measure. The key thing about both these terms is that whilst they may be *extended*, there's always the implication they're *of finite duration*. One often needs to distinguish this type of "circumstantial" excess from the *constant* consumption of an alcoholic (which may continue until it results in untimely death).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You may be right. 'He went on a binge/bender over Christmas'. Personally I wouldn't use it in that way because I have never thought of it like that, but perhaps others do.

Answer (score 2):

***Marathon drinking sessions*** could describe concentrated drinking episodes lasting anything between lasting several hours to several days.

Google books offer instances of the expression being used [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=1gb9VbzIIREC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=%22marathon+drinking+session%22&source=bl&ots=jjn4lhd5Rn&sig=EYiWkZ63dQKZtxAeBSskSNzHvPY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tj_FUryGH4q5yQOh_YHIDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22marathon%20drinking%20session%22&f=false), [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=wMgCyBd4arAC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=%22marathon+drinking+session%22&source=bl&ots=pRbb7Yzctp&sig=L_ZVcbPS-rkMmsmBL58vIwtwmDM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tj_FUryGH4q5yQOh_YHIDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22marathon%20drinking%20session%22&f=false) and [here.](http://books.google.it/books?id=SGuF4mhxFQEC&pg=PA166&dq=%22marathon+drinking+session%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1z_FUs-mFajpywOm24LQDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22marathon%20drinking%20session%22&f=false)

Alternative terms that are well-known in both the US and the UK  are

- [**drinking bout**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drinking-bout)
- [**toot**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toot) *n. a binge, esp. a period of drunken revelry.* [v.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toot) *to go on a drinking binge*

  > We spent the whole holiday tooting
  >   We spent the whole holiday on a drinking bout

The period after an intense bout of heavy drinking is typically called *hangover*.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangover)

> A **hangover** /ˈhæŋoʊvər/ (medical terminology: veisalgia) is the
>   experience of various unpleasant physiological and psychological
>   effects following consumption of alcoholic beverages and is generally
>   characterized by a feeling of severe discomfort that may last more
>   than 24 hours. Typical symptoms of a hangover may include headache,
>   drowsiness, concentration problems, dry mouth, dizziness, fatigue,
>   gastrointestinal complaints, sweating, nausea, hyper-excitability and
>   anxiety.

*Sobriety* is however the term which describes the period of abstinence from alcohol. Wordnet defines it as,
[*the state of being sober and not intoxicated by alcohol.*](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&r=1&s=sobriety&i=1&h=11000000#c)

> **Sobriety** may refer to being clear of immediate or residual effects of
>   mind-altering substances, referring to a specific substance that is
>   the concern of a particular 12 step program (alcohol, opiates,
>   marijuana, tobacco). "**Clean and sober**" is a commonly used phrase,
>   which refers to someone having an extended period without drugs or
>   alcohol in their body.

[<sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobriety#12_step_programs)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's been a ***week-long [piss-up](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/piss-up)***.

Now it's over, I'm on a ***[detox](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/detox_1?q=detox)***.

Comment: I'm assuming piss-up is a British thing? I've never heard that before...

Answer (score 1):

Piss up, yes, also 'booze' - booze up, boozy Christmas, boozy week, etc. I'm in the UK.